# Align text in <li> after bullet

Tags: css, html-lists

How can I align the text to have the rest of the sentence "drawn up" to be like the sentences above?

I've tried adding:

```
padding-inline-start: 0px;
padding-inline-end: 0px;
```

But that doesnt work...

```html
<div style="padding: 4% 4% 4% 6%; margin-bottom: 4%; box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-right: 0px !important;">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h1>02. Offer</h1>

<ul>
 <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Request for company information</li>
 <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; A concept offer is presented in person</li>
 <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; When agreed an intention agreement is drawn up</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img alt="" src="https://curaeos.cms.dentconnect.eu/dynamic/media/22/images/curaeos-acquisition-process-offer-300x250.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 250px; float:right;" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you use bootstrap? if yes what version?

Comment: Why do you need the spaces? Just remove the spaces and it should work as expected.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `.padding-left` to your `li` elements, and delete your `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 50%;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 4% 4% 4% 6%; margin-bottom: 4%; box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-right: 0px !important;">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h1>02. Offer</h1>

<ul>
 <li>Request for company information</li>
 <li>A concept offer is presented in person</li>
 <li>When agreed an intention agreement is drawn up</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img alt="" src="https://curaeos.cms.dentconnect.eu/dynamic/media/22/images/curaeos-acquisition-process-offer-300x250.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 250px; float:right;" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `&nbsp;` is causing it. Why not use padding instead of manually adding spaces?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Request for company information</li>
    <li>A concept offer is presented in person</li>
    <li>When agreed an intention agreement is drawn up</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```